# Looking for a good distribution to analyse market dynamics

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

I'm experimenting with replacement for normal distribution for my models.

So far, I tried Gamma and Inverse Gamma distributions. Gamma significantly underestimates the probability of the extreme events, while Inverse Gamma overestimates it by several orders of magnitude.

I'm probably looking for something in-between.

What other distributions should I investigate?

**UPDATE**
Here are observed frequencies of some of the events

```
 0.0001 13917082
 0.0002 985595
 0.0003 251837
 0.0004 87272
 0.0005 33259
 0.0006 15681
 0.0007 7536
 0.0008 4079
 0.0009 2235
 0.001  1239
 0.0011 891
 0.0012 516
 0.0013 359
 0.0014 236
 0.0015 185
 0.0016 125
 0.0017 99
 0.0018 81
 0.0019 70
 0.002  33
 0.0021 57
 0.0022 32
 0.0023 19
 0.0024 29
 0.0025 22
 0.0026 18
 0.0027 9
 0.0028 17
 0.0029 9
 0.003  9
 0.0031 10
 0.0032 8
 0.0033 6
 0.0034 2
 0.0035 2
 0.0036 5
 0.0037 3
 0.0038 3
 0.0039 1
 0.004  4
 0.0041 3
 0.0042 2
 0.0043 2
 0.0045 1
 0.0046 1
 0.0047 3
 0.0049 2
 0.0052 2
 0.0053 2
 0.0054 1
 0.0056 1
 0.0057 2
 0.0058 1
 0.006  2
 0.0063 1
 0.0065 1
 0.007  2
 0.0071 1
 0.0075 1
 0.0079 1
 0.008  1
 0.0081 1
 0.0082 1
 0.0085 1
 0.0087 1
 0.0092 1
 0.0093 1
 0.0099 1
 0.0103 1
 0.0112 1
 0.0115 1
 0.0124 1
 0.0126 1
```

Comment: It depends on your data and your assumptions about them.  Could you provide specific information to help people formulate good answers?

Comment: I'm analysing distribution of 1 minute price fluctuations. I'm using fitting to find the best distribution and compare predicted probabilities to probabilities actually found in the data. Does this answer your question?

Comment: It helps--but it also suggests that fitting some well-known mathematical distribution to the data might not be a great solution.  It would help to have quantitative information about the "extreme events" to which you refer.

Comment: I've updated the question with event frequencies